# best way for Jetty to serve multiple wars hot

Tags: web-applications, jetty, tomcat6, ubuntu-10.04, web-deployment

I have a new 64-bit Ubuntu server with 4G of memory.  I need to serve several (6 now, maybe 50 later) war files as their own context roots.  (Similar apps from a commmon code base branded differently). I'm more comfortable with Jetty than Apache.

I can just drop the wars in /usr/share/jetty6/webapps.

But how can I add new ones without bouncing the server?

It seems like there should be a way to use the scanInterval feature from ContextDeployer (which works with exploded directories) and implement it for WebAppDeployer (for wars) - am I missing something obvious here?

If I just explode my own wars as I deploy, would that do the trick? (Is there a setting that does this?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK, I guess the crickets chirping mean nobody has ever wanted to do this..

So FYI, the (obvious?) solution was to drop [Jetty](http://dannyayers.com/2007/11/16/installing-jetty-on) and go with [Tomcat6](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-tomcat-6-on-ubuntu-9-04-jaunty.html), which works this way by default.

The only gotcha was about how to make it serve port 80 (because LinkSys routers, unlike nice DLinks, can't change ports as they forward).

It was fairly clear that you need to edit the Catalina connector to use port 80 in /etc/tomcat6/server.xml, but the above how-to-link fails to mention that you also have to edit the last line in /etc/default/tomcat6 to enable authbind too.  I found that out [here](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/a-better-tomcat-for-ubuntu-and-debian/).

Also, FYI if you instead try an iptable solution, that will dork [TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com/), which is my new preferred way of remote admin vs VNC which requires more ports to be passed along (and it's not as scalable since you have to open ports and pass them to each host)